# How can I alter DataTable defaults / attributes without overriding core files?

Tags: datatables

Example use case:

When viewing a Contact, on the Relationships tab we'd like the DataTables to default to showing 50 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter any DataTable table through it's API as long as you are in Civi's jQuery context (CRM.$)

You could use hook_civicrm_alterTemplateFile or hook_civicrm_buildForm for example to load your script:

```
Civi::resources()->addScriptFile( 'my-extension', 'js/alterDataTables.js' );
```

Then in your js:

```
// alterDataTables.js file
CRM.$( function( $ ) {
  // get and itarate over all dataTables
  $( '.dataTable' ).map( function( index, table ) {
    // get dataTable instance
    $( table ).DataTable()
      // set page length
      .page.len( 2 )
      // draw table
      .draw()
  } );
} );
```

The above example was given to me so may have worked in some places e.g. when the dataTable is available on page load. For my use-case I needed to work with the 'Relationships' tab tables when viewing a Contact. In this case, $('.dataTable') would select nothing unless I responded to the ajax event, in which case I also needed to add once() to avoid an infinite loop of redrawing tables:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var dt = $('.dataTable');
    if (dt.length) {
      $('.dataTable').once().map(function(index, table) {
        // get dataTable instance
        $(table).once().DataTable()
          // set page length
          .page.len(50)
          // draw table
          .draw()
      });
    }
  }); 
});
```